# PrintDocument issues with Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard 64-bit

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008-r2

It seems that when trying to use the **System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument** namespace on a Windows 7 64-bit (SP1) box it works great.  But trying the same code on a Server 2008 R2 64-bit (SP1) box and it just hangs in the code.  No exceptions are thrown, etc...

Here is a snippet of my code...

```
private bool PrintTIF(string sPrinter, string sFile)
{
    try
    {
        //Open file for printing
        WriteEvent(105, "Opening the file for printing using streamreader...", CustomLogTool.EventLogEntryTypeExtentions.Debug);
        m_PrinterFile = new StreamReader(sFile);

        //Set the document name
        WriteEvent(105, "Set the document name.", CustomLogTool.EventLogEntryTypeExtentions.Debug);
        m_Printer.DocumentName = Path.GetFileName(sFile);

        //Print file
        WriteEvent(105, "Sending the file to the printer...", CustomLogTool.EventLogEntryTypeExtentions.Debug);
        m_Printer.Print();
        m_PrinterFilesPrinting.Add(new PrintInfo(sFile, null, sPrinter));

        //Close file
        WriteEvent(105, "Closing the file and destorying the streamreader object.", CustomLogTool.EventLogEntryTypeExtentions.Debug);
        m_PrinterFile.Close();

        //Success
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        try { m_PrinterFile.Close(); }
        catch { }
        WriteEvent(201, ex.Message, CustomLogTool.EventLogEntryTypeExtentions.Debug);

        return false;
    }
}
```

I get log events up to "Sending the file to the printer...".  The I get nothing, I expect to get my error 201 message in the exception.  But I get nothing.  It's as if the program is hung.  I'm guessing it's due to something that has been changed from Win7 (SP1) to Server2008R2(SP1).  Any ideas?

Comment: Never, *never*, **never** attempt to print from a service.  You can't see the printer driver alerts.

Comment: The whole point of my app is to print from a service...  Why could I not just wrap those "printer driver alerts" into an event log entry?  Can you possibly elaborate more on the "printer driver alerts"?  What are they, how can I see them or gain access to them etc...  Anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
I figured out what my issue was.  It had to do with the fact I had the wrong printer selected that whole time!  A LOT of wasted time for such a simple thing but it did lead me down a path to approach debugging it a different way.  After I started using the correct printer I then found out my next issue was a TIFF file that was not an actual TIFF file.  It happen to be a 0 byte test file I forgot I through in the test directory.

**My New Approach To Debugging These Service Printer Issues:**
The best way to find out what's going on is to come out of the "Service Realm" for a bit.  Compile it as a ***Debug*** build and that way you can run it as a console app.  Having it built as a ***Release*** build requires you to run it as a service and will NOT let you run it manually.  When I built it as a Debug release I ran it on the server from the directory and then a Windows dialog popped up...  It was asking me what I wanted to save my file as.  Soon after I figured out that it was the default 'Microsoft XPS Document Writer' printer!

I then went in and changed the printer to the one I wanted (via code)...

```
PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pc = new StandardPrintController();
pd.PrintController = pc;
// Yadda Yadda Yadda...
pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "My Printer Name";
```

Hope it helps someone else out and saves them some time too!  Good Luck!